# UK visa from US: forgot to add prior expired passport

Tags: visas, uk

I have filled in the UK visa online application form and in the “passports” section - I entered only the current passport and the last passport info. I have one more passport from 15 years ago that I didn’t enter. What can I do now? The online form is submitted and There is no amendment possible.

Should I submit that old expired passport (not included in the application) anyway? I am going for biometrics in 4 days and then have to ship to Newyork.

Should I include a letter stating I am attaching this exprired passport and it is not included in the application. What is recommended?

Answer (score 2):

here are your options.

1. Contact UKVI on their 'very expensive' modes of communication via [this](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk) link, and state your application reference number and ask for guidance.
2. If the above step does not work out, since your bio metrics are not done yet, you always have the option of withdrawing the application. Your visa fee and IHS free will be refunded in this scenario.
3. Third step would be to go ahead with the bio metric and submit a letter stating that you had missed a piece of information and submit your omitted passport details during the application process at the visa centre.

Hope it works out. Please update your experience once you pick an option.

**Note: The above advice is just that, an 'advice', I am in no way qualified to give you professional guidance nor am I an expert in UK immigration.**

Comment: Thanks. On option 3, to be clear, is your feedback on taking the old expired passport along with me to the US application support center during biometrics and show them and get it added?

Comment: @GaneshS No, you cannot do that at the ASC. They can only take your biometrics. They cannot make changes to your visa application.

Comment: @Michael H: thanks. Will try to call up the UKVI folks and see if that gets me anywhere.